# Speed Up Unity Dash Loading Programs

Tags: unity, 13.10, hud

Each time I open dash for the first time since booting, it takes ages to load programs on it. I have to wait for like a minute or so and then programs appears. I have online stuffs disabled so its only offline stuffs. Is there a way to speed things up?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to know each step `Unity` is doing from `Dash` opening to the end of `search` so I could schedule the `indexing` for each `system startup`...

Comment: Did you get it? I have not yet resolved this!

Comment: Nah, this is my smiliar question bounted by others: 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/506806/how-to-make-faster-first-search-at-unity-dash-way-slower-than-second-one

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to turn off online searches and a few other tweaks that will speed up the search dash.

Install `Unity Tweak Tool` here [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/)
** *Have caution with this program even though you can reset the settings changed, you may have issues that conflict with eachother.

After installing open it up and click on the `Search` Settings Under `Unity`

You can turn off `Background Blur` and `Clear History` as well as a few other options that will speed it up nicely.

[image: The following screenshot shows some settings that help speed it up dramatically]

Comment: the problem seems that Unity builds index each time you access dash for the first time since boot. After accessing once problem is gone. I do not know how to tell unity to keep programs index unti I install/Uninstall a thing!