# How to make faster first search at Unity-Dash? Way slower than second one

Tags: files, unity-dash, performance, search, indexing

After a reboot, the first search using `Unity Dash` will be slower (15 sec) than the second search (seems instant), on my system at least. I guess this is because `file index` is cleared after a reboot and recreated as soon as first `Unity Dash` search is done.

If this is the case, auto-recreating index at system start-up should work. I could imagine for example automatically running some command at the system startup for gathering info **before** it is requested by user via Unity search.

---

I'm interested particularly in searching for programs.

I have disabled `online search` for better performance while no interest in that.

---

My current machine configuration:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1 x64 on HP 655
Processor: AMD E2-1800 APU (2x 1700 MHz)
Graphics: Radeon HD 7340 driven by xOrg "Gallium 0.4 on AMD PALM"
Memory: 4 GB (real 3.6 GB)
HDD: ATA Hitachi HTS54505
```

Theoretical benchmarks: [CPU](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD%20E2-1800%20APU), [HDD](http://www.harddrivebenchmark.net/hdd.php?hdd=Hitachi%20HTS54505). I will benchmark those myself eventually...

Comment: Related question:http://askubuntu.com/q/475664/256099 can be started bounty

Answer (score 1):

Following topics may help you:-

- Question about indexing and search may be found from :- [How does Unity's dash index and search work?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37814)
- Speed up for searching programs, visit [How to speed up search for locally installed applications in Ubuntu 13.10's Unity Dash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/382055)
- Also have a look at [How to speed up the Dash response?](https://askubuntu.com/q/153831) :- [Compiz Config tweak](https://askubuntu.com/a/382631/256099) may help.

I know that this is not exact answer of your question as quoted:-

> I guess this is because file index is cleared after a reboot and
>   recreated as soon as first Unity Dash search is done.

Is still unanswered and requires more attention.

Comment: second search also/still is fast without doing this steps that you suggested.

Comment: Thanks :) . I didn't know about `compizconfig-settings-manager`. Although it seems the first `Unity` search delay relates to files / index / HDD not the graphics or RAM. I'm not having slideshow. And the same result would be for example 2 hours after system startup.

Comment: Also visit http://askubuntu.com/q/382055/256099

Comment: preload is not good for slower systems because it's using lots of RAM and CPU, and that has nothing with unity search

Comment: preload doesn't change anything for me -1

Comment: @Alen finally I've removed recommending `preload`.

Comment: @meles Revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're only interested in the Dash to start application, you can simply uninstall lenses with `sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-lens-[lensName]`.
As advised by BullfrogBlues [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107701/how-to-disable-lenses-in-the-in-the-dash-menu), that most likely means removing all of them except for `unity-lens-applications` and possibly `unity-lens-files`.

In case you like the Ubuntu system but feel like Unity is getting more and more crowded with functionalities you don't use, you can also consider moving to [some other Ubuntu flavor](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours). On my side I am now pretty happy with *Ubuntu Gnome* and a customized *Cairo-dock*!

Answer (score 0):

Like the asker, I too mainly used the Dash for opening applications. There are things (e.g. those mentioned above by others) that can speed up the Dash. However, I found start startup speed remained an issue - presumably due to re-indexing. The best solution for me was to use "Gnome Do" instead. It's very neat and very fast. It's also in the ubuntu repositories and can be triggered from a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this application.  It is called "Adaptive Readahead daemon".  It is available from the Ubuntu repository.
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/preload/

I must say it has certainly sped up launching or doing anything in ubuntu from the desktop on my system.  However I haven't really tested searching stuff before I installed it, and after I installed it.

When I get back home I'll see how fast it is to search now that I've got it installed after a reboot.  However that said, I do have 16GB or RAM where the daemon caches all the stuff intelligently based on my past usage patterns.